# How to make this more clean and combine the 2 arrays so that each index will equal the other,

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I want to replace doing the two index of each array into something more simple, the purpose of this is to create a random generated questions that are answered by users and a score is given at the end, and add a feature that tells me the correct answer when i give the incorrect answer

```
Console.WriteLine("Question");
int point = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Random Quesitons = new Random();
    int q = Quesitons.Next(5);

    string[] Question = new string[10];

    Question[0] = "Who owns Apple";
    Question[1] = " 2+2 =";
    Question[2] = " 5+5 =";
    Question[3] = " how old are you ?";
    Question[4] = "what planet do we live on ?";
    Question[5] = "what is the capital of Egypt?";
    Question[6] = "how many big pyramids in Giza?";
    Question[7] = "where are you from ?";
    Question[8] = "what type of phone do you use";
    Question[9] = "what type of laptop do you use?";

    Console.WriteLine(Question[q]);

    string[] Answers = new string[10];
    Answers[0] = "Steve Jobs";
    Answers[1] = "4";
    Answers[2] = "10";
    Answers[3] = "21";
    Answers[4] = "Earth";
    Answers[5] = "Cairo";
    Answers[6] = "3";
    Answers[7] = "Egypt";
    Answers[8] = "iphone";
    Answers[9] = "acer";

    string a = Console.ReadLine();

    Question[0] = Answers[0];
    Question[1] = Answers[1];
    Question[2] = Answers[2];
    Question[3] = Answers[3];
    Question[4] = Answers[4];
    Question[5] = Answers[5];
    Question[6] = Answers[6];
    Question[7] = Answers[7];
    Question[8] = Answers[8];
    Question[9] = Answers[9];



    if (a == Question[q])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("correct Answer");
        point += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Answer");
        point -= 0;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("your final score is : "+point);
```

Comment: Rather than parallel arrays, consider a class to keep related data together

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```cs
record QuizQuestion(string Question, string Answer);

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Question");

        var quiz = new List<QuizQuestion>()
        {
            new QuizQuestion("Who owns Apple", "Steve Jobs"),
            new QuizQuestion("2+2 =", "4"),
            new QuizQuestion("5+5 =", "10"),
        };

        var point = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var q = Random.Shared.Next(quiz.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(quiz[q].Question);
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if (quiz[q].Answer.Equals(answer, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("correct Answer");
                point += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Answer");
                point -= 0;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"your final score is : {point}");
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way where I can use contain to add the value of indexes from the question array to index array ?

Answer (score -1):

As you can see the way to make index[x] of questions array  equal to index[x] of answers array is just simply adding the command
**Question[q] = Answers[q];**

```
Console.WriteLine("Question");
int point = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Random Quesitons = new Random();
    int q = Quesitons.Next(5);

    string[] Question = new string[10];

    Question[0] = "Who owns Apple";
    Question[1] = " 2+2 =";
    Question[2] = " 5+5 =";
    Question[3] = " how old are you ?";
    Question[4] = "what planet do we live on ?";
    Question[5] = "what is the capital of Egypt?";
    Question[6] = "how many big pyramids in Giza?";
    Question[7] = "where are you from ?";
    Question[8] = "what type of phone do you use";
    Question[9] = "what type of laptop do you use?";

    Console.WriteLine(Question[q]);

    string[] Answers = new string[10];
    Answers[0] = "Steve Jobs";
    Answers[1] = "4";
    Answers[2] = "10";
    Answers[3] = "21";
    Answers[4] = "Earth";
    Answers[5] = "Cairo";
    Answers[6] = "3";
    Answers[7] = "Egypt";
    Answers[8] = "iphone";
    Answers[9] = "acer";

    string a = Console.ReadLine();

   // Console.WriteLine(Answers[q]);

    Question[q] = Answers[q];
 
    if (a == Question[q])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("correct Answer");
        point += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Answer");
        point -= 0;
    }
    if(a != Question[q])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the correct is is = " + Question[q]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Good Job!");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("your final score is : "+point);
```